# ImportError: cannot import name 'EMPTY_VALUES' from 'django.forms.fields'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-cms

I installed djangocms in existing django project, following the instructions: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html

but when I run `py manage.py cms check` or `py manage.py migrate` I have this error:

> File
> "C:\Users\usuario\Envs\env_cuid_lab\lib\site-packages\cms\forms\fields.py",
> line 4, in 
> from django.forms.fields import EMPTY_VALUES ImportError: cannot import name 'EMPTY_VALUES' from 'django.forms.fields'
> (C:\Users\usuario\Envs\env_cuid_lab\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Django are you using?

I assume you are using Django 3.1.2? if so then downgrade to 3.0 because DjangoCMS does not is not compatible with 3.1 at the moment.

This should help : pip install Django==3.0

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html#requirements

Answer (score 2):

`Django 3.2` updated the follows:

`from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1061f5243646b4c9b8a758f8a36c9e2ccdded1cf/django/core/validators.py#L16

Comment: I'm in the process of upgrading from django 2.2 to 3.2, and this fixed it for me. Thanks!